# post Laravel and VUEJS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i´m traying initiate with vueJS and i´m doing a aplication that update a register of my DB but always returned a 405 error in my web browser console. I´m trying send my token in request axios, and i think that is my problem, because with ajax always have to send token in the header petition. this is my actual code vueJS, HTML and route Laravel.

thanks

**VUEJS**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('usuarios-component', require('./components/usuariosComponent.vue').default);


 // inicio de VUE

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#contenedorVue',
    data:{
            id: '',
            nombreUsuario: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            direccion: '',
            token: '',
            arrayTasks:[],
        },
        methods: {
            enviar(){
                let url = '/actualizarDatos';
                axios.post(url, {
                    id: this.id,
                    nombreUsuario: this.nombreUsuario,
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password,
                    direccion: this.direccion,
                    token: this.token,
                }).then(function(response){
                    this.arrayTasks = response.data;
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    @include('layouts.sidebar')

    <!-- SE ESTABLECE V-MODEL para usarlo con vue, es como el ID -->
    
    <div id="contenedorVue">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" v-model="token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="email">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="nombreUsuario" value="{{$usuario->nombre}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" v-model="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{$usuario->email}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password" value="{{$usuario->password}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
                        <textarea v-model="direccion" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="3">
                            {{$usuario->direccion}}
                        </textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{$usuario->id}}" v-model="id">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- EMPEZAMOS LA FUNCIONALIDAD CON VUE DE ESTA MANERA LE DAMOS FUNCIONALIDAD AL BOTON-->
                <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5" @click="enviar">Actualizar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


@endsection
```

**CONSOLE ERROR**

```
1:1 POST http://www.bonos.local/datosPersonales/1 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

**error post laravel**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

**ROUTES**

```
Route::get('/datosPersonales/{id}', 'HomeController@datosPersonales')->name('datosPersonales');

Route::post('/actualizarDatos', 'UsuariosController@actualizarDatosPersonales')->name('actualizarDatosPersonales');
```

**image**

[image]

**image 2**
[image]

Comment: @kerbh0lz thanks for your response. No my first route it´s for view. my second route is for update

Comment: @KamleshPaul i´m hitting for my sidebar in other document web. It´s the first route

Comment: Can you verify this using postman or similar? Make sure the problem is not with backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to prevent default submit form

```html
 <form method="post">
```

to

```
 <form @submit.prevent="enviar">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5" type="submit">Actualizar</button>
  </form>
```

here button need to have `type="submit"` so once you click that button it will submit form

here `post` and `get` will handel in `enviar()` function

ref link https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: Thakns for your response, this it´s other thing that i want to do. Now the rror in console is:Error: Request failed with status code 405
    at createError (app.js:699)
    at settle (app.js:960)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:168)

Comment: 405 but token is sent

Comment: in other petition for this route, i can see all my data sent

Comment: yes. 405, i can see my data, but i can´t to get my controller

Comment: i add 2 pictures whit my problem. my route that get 405 it´s "actualizarDatos"

Comment: thanks for your time, i show my web.php and it´s ok Route::get for view and Route::post for update...  in network i have two pettiton one all data with out id, i think that i have any problem with {{$usuario->id}} in my blade that don´t show my id. The other data it´s ok, i want to say that all data that i´m introducing in my form, not data with {{}}

Comment: `405 (Method Not Allowed)` it means your hitting url is not accepting that `method` like `get` and `post` ... so on so this is not related to form data it about `url` action

Comment: yes i understand you, but i don´t undestand why i can´t recive my data in my controller... and always 405 error. I don't know how to continue

Comment: check the 405 url and `web.php` url

Comment: thanks for your time. I can see now, that when i send my form, first i recive a status 301 and after 405... in my web.php its all ok....

Comment: @scorpions great means it does solve your problem .?

Comment: no... only, that first get 301 and i think than this prevent go to other url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223349/discussion-between-kamlesh-paul-and-scorpions).

Answer (score 0):

it´s essential to do

```
npm run watch
```

or

```
npm run dev
```

for all changes be appliead... sorry for my numb